# Laravel download file is not triggering the download on the client even though it is sending the file

Tags: php, html, laravel, browser

I am calling a method in a laravel controller that returns a file that I want to download to the browser. The file is an audio file. Here is the controller:

```
    public function getAudioFile(Request $request)
{
    //This is the id we are looking to pull
    $uid = $request->uniqueid;
    $audioServices = new AudioServices();
    $pathToFile = $audioServices->getWavFile($uid);
    $name = $uid . '.wav';
    return Response::download($pathToFile, $name);
}
```

Everything works fine. And the file is returned to the browser but it doesn't trigger the actual download file event in the browser. The response just sits in memory. Here is the response generated:

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: public
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1563974948.9449586.wav
Content-Length: 6409004
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2019 18:23:47 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jul 2019 18:23:44 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
<snip>
```

And if I try to preview the response, I can see the wav file's binary data. But, neither firefox nor chrome actually 'package' the file and store it in their downloads directory.

I am sure I am missing something small, but I have spent two hours without making any headway. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious if that filename is causing issues. We had a problem with special characters freaking apache out when we tried to return filenames with them, and `1563974948.9449586.wav` seems weird. Can you put a vanilla `test.wav` in the directory and serve that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not have any more success.

Answer (score 1):

I finally dug up the issue. The call to the controller is from an ajax call. This, for some reason, causes problems when the return is a downloadable file. The solution is clunky. I wrapped each call to the controller (because it is a table with many file links) in a form element and did away with the clean ajax click functionality. Clunky - but it works. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: This is seriously one of those answers that you're supposed to spend HOURS searching and it's buried in some obscure comment in a blog post about an ambiguously related topic that you read out of complete desperation.  You were hitting the EXACT same issue I was and this was the answer.  Man I hate development (I don't) but holy @*#& did I get that ole adrenaline rush when that zip file finally downloaded packed full of images.

Thanks for sharing what you figured out Mark C!!  Dunno why someone down voted your question but I popped it back up to `0` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I always use headers so client browsers  know content type. Can you try once this.

```
$headers = [ 'Content-Type' => 'audio/wav', ];
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

Comment: The headers were the second part of the post. And the Content-Type is there.

Answer (score 0):

// try it

public function downloadAudiobook($id)
{
 if (Auth::user())

```
    {
        $userID = Auth::user()->id;
        $download = AudiobookDownload::where(['user_id' => $userID, 'audiobooks_id' => $id])->first();


       if (empty($download->user_id))
        {

            $download = new AudiobookDownload;
            $download->user_id = $user_id;
            $download->audiobooks_id = $id;
            $download->save();

        }

       $audiobook = AudioBook::find($id);


        $download = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $audiobook->audiobook_location;
```

return response()->download($download);
       }
       else
       {
           return redirect()->route('login')->with('validate', 'success');
       }
}